# Adding deep link dynamically to the manifest file in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I want to dynamically add the URLs I get from any API or using firebase remote config to my manifest file. What are the advantages and disadvantages of this method regarding this issue? If we can, how can we do it?

I couldn't get anywhere with my research.

Comment: `If we can, how can we do it?` You should have asked that before asking for -dis-advantages.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the advantages and disadvantages of this method regarding this issue?

One disadvantage is: it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there any chance you could provide information as to why it couldn't be done?

Comment: @volkandincer: Deeplinks are defined in the manifest. The manifest itself is read-only at runtime, and there is no API for adding new deeplinks.